# spring is not redirecting to default target url?

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication. authentication is working fine. but after authentication it is not redirecting to the html that have mentioned using default target url in spring security configuration file. i am getting simple message **Success**. but not the html page that have configured. i have added below line for redirection.

```
<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/welcome.html"/>
```

am i missing anything to configure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If a user is sent to the login page after requesting a protected resource, they will be sent to the originally requested page after successful login. The [default-target-url](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login-default-target-url) will only be used if the user logged in without requesting a protected resource first (i.e. they navigated directly to the login page). If you always want to go to the default-target-url you can specify [always-use-default-target](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login-always-use-default-target)="true" as shown in the example below

```
<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
            default-target-url="/welcome.html" 
            always-use-default-target="true"/>
```

Comment: That's the problem. Even though I have only default-target-url, after successful login, it forwared me to strange /FAVICON.ICO.

Comment: that is what i was looking for ;)

Answer (score 13):

I had similar problem and above answer gave me a hint, but since I am using configs directly from Java class following helped me:

In  [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html) you can find:

defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse)

Hence when changed

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
```

to

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
```

problem was solved.

Comment: thank you this helped me. Looking at the javadoc:
/**
  * Specifies where users will be redirected after authenticating successfully if
  * they have not visited a secured page prior to authenticating or {@code alwaysUse}
  * is true.*/    

what i understand from above is that if one has NOT visited a secured page first then redirection will NOT happen unless the flag is set to true.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting gotcha here is if the browser requests a resource that requires an authenticated session - e.g. requesting a javascript file which requires the user to be logged in, this would generate a 403 error which if you have error pages configured in spring or web.xml would redirect the user to - however the user would never see this.

Then when the user does log in, the last thing spring thinks the user requested was an error page and so the user gets directed to the error page and not the default page as you configure in spring

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question, but some users can have this problem now too.

1. Make sure that you can access the `welcome.html` page (relative to the context path). You can remove `intercept-url` or access it directly after login.
2. Make sure you also specified the `always-use-default-target="true"`
3. If you specified session-management make sure you're not redirected first to the `invalid-session-url`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image, there is some kind of bad design (IMO It should always redirect to `the default-target-url`). When you go to the login url from a forbidden resource, it will redirect you to that URL and not going thru the `default-target-url`.
Just use `always-use-default-target="true"` and you will have the desire behavior

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj9ou.png