# Spring security not hitting default-target-url after successful authtication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have implemented spring-security in my application, my spring-security.xml has following form-login tag.

```
<form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/dashboard.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

I want to login from /login.htm and after successful authetication I want user to hit dashboard.htm. Everythig is working fine except for the fact that after successfull authetication it doesn't hit /dashboard.htm but hits the context..but if I manually type dashboard.htm in url then everything works fine...Yes..I have the implementation of authticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: Trying to activate debug leve for spring security and see what is going one. Are you using other filters? As urlrewrite?

Comment: I'm no expert in Spring Security but why do you have both a default-target-url and authentication-success-handler ? You could remove default-target-url and do the redirect in the success handler

Comment: Blitzkr1eg is right, you should not have both authentication-success-handler-ref and default-target-url. From the description of authentication-success-handler-ref: "Reference to an AuthenticationSuccessHandler bean which should be used to handle a successful authentication request. **Should not be used in combination with default-target-url (or always-use-default-target-url) as the 
 implementation should always deal with navigation to the subsequent destination**"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try removing the `default-target-url` attribute and add the following:

```
<b:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.example.CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <b:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/dashboard.htm"/>
</b:bean>
```

Comment: @vasilakis will that always redirect to target url be default or not ?

Answer (score 8):

```
<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.example.LoginSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/security/success"/>
    <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

     @Override
     public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
         request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 60); //one hour
         System.out.println("Session set up for 60min");
         super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
      }
}
```

Comment: A great answer!

Comment: For anyone using purely Java config, You can set the properties in the constuctor         public LoginSuccessHandler(){ super();
          setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
          setDefaultTargetUrl("/security/success");
        }

Answer (score 6):

I use this suggestion from the question [spring is not redirecting to default target url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657947/spring-is-not-redirecting-to-default-target-url).  I tried this and it is working.

```
<form-login login-page="/login.htm" 
default-target-url="/dashboard.htm" 
always-use-default-target="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image, there is some kind of bad design (IMO It always redirect to the `default-target-url`).
When you go to the login form from a forbidden resource, it will redirect you to that URL and not going thru `the default-target-url`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj9ou.png