# How can I change j_spring_security_check?

Tags: spring, zk

I'm working with ZK and spring.
I downloaded 2 different project that now I try to merge. My problem is in this part of code:

```
<html:form action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST" xmlns:html="native">
```

that is in the file login.zul. I found these lines in web.xml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I saw that if I change `/*` with `/login.zul` it happened that in my url becomes: `localhost:8080/myProject/j_spring_security_check` and I saw *error 404*.

If I didn't change my url is `localhost:8080/myProject/` and the page `index.zul` works correctely.

But `index.zul` is in the same folder as `login.zul`.

I saw the same error also if I set `/index.zul` in state of "/*".

How can I decide another url in stead of `/*`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to change `/*`? You're not supposed to change it - and certainly not to `/login.zul` - the login page is not one that needs access permissions. The security filter should protect your entire webapp, and in your spring config you can provide a more fine-grained configuration.

Comment: /login.zul is on for an example. I need that my portal after login go to my panel control. But in this case return to home. How can I go to my panel control that are called panel.zul and it is in a different folder of login.zul?

Answer (score 3):

The above URL pattern /* declares that you want to protect all your pages. It has nothing to with the fact, which page do you want to load after the successfull login.

The title is also missleading, j_spring_security_check is just the default URL for Spring Security login form submission: SpringSec will start his authentication module (that is username/password checking) when a request to this URL comes. You do not want to change it. You may change it if you for example do not want to tell the world that you uses Spring Security, or you do not want to change your existing login form that uses an other action attribute.

You may have a configuration XML for Spring Security like spring-security.xml or an equivalent Java based configuration) - with a tag  in it. You need to set the default-target-url attribute of that tag as

> `<form-login login-page="/some_dir/login.zul" default-target-url="/some_other_dir/panel.zul"`

You should use relative URLs inside your webapp.

You may have an authentication-success-handler-ref instead of default-target-urlin a more complicated situation, [but you should not mix them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672850/spring-security-not-hitting-default-target-url-after-successful-authtication) .