# Spring is always rediting to default target URL after successful login

Tags: java, spring, redirect, authentication, spring-security

SpringFramework security is redirecting me to default target URL after successful login that I have defined (Scenario 1), but I user will specify some other location and it turns out that login is required SpringFramework is also redirecting to default location instead of location specified by the user (Scenario 2).

Scenario 1:

- User enters: http://pageAddress/
- User is redirected to login page http://pageAddress/login.action
- After successful login it is redirected to default location: http://pageAddress/default.action

Scenario 2:

- User enters: http://pageAddress/someSpecificLocation.action
- User is redirected to login page http://pageAddress/login.action
- After successful login it is redirected to default location: http://pageAddress/default.action (WRONG !)

I have alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl=false. Wouldn't that be enough ?
I use custom filter chain instead of http tag because of basic authentication required for web-service

SpringFramework version: 3.0.5

Security configuration:

```
<bean id="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilterWithASCFalse" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <!--property name="allowSessionCreation" value="false" TODO no property like this exist any more - probably not needed /-->
</bean>

<bean id="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />

<bean id="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Spring Security Application" />
</bean>

<bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandlerImpl" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" />

<bean id="basicExceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandlerImpl" />
</bean>

<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="formLoginFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <!--property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login!login.action" / to be investigated ! -->
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
</bean>


<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.action?authenticationFailed=true" />
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/search.action" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
</bean>


<bean id="formLoginEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.action" />
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter" />

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="formLoginEntryPoint" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandlerImpl" />
</bean>


<bean id="accessManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessManager" />

    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/bsh*" access="ROLE_Bsh"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_Administrators"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_Users,ROLE_Administrators"/>
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
      </property>

</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/c/**" filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/i/**" filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/j/**" filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/accessdenied.jsp" filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/login.action*" filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/services/**"
            filters="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilterWithASCFalse,logoutFilter,
                   basicAuthenticationFilter,basicExceptionTranslationFilter,
                   filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,formLoginFilter,
                     securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,
                     exceptionTranslationFilter,
                     filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think you require default-target-url to be true...

Answer (score 3):

Got it! I had to replace SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler with SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Answer (score 0):

Solution for incorrect URL when an authentication success happens:

- Look for the response of the user "Mircea Stanciu"
  [Spring security not hitting default-target-url after successful authtication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672850/spring-security-not-hitting-default-target-url-after-successful-authtication)

  It says that you must create a class rewriting the Spring Security's **LoginSuccessHandler class** and **create a bean in your application-security.xml** to that class

AND

- In your application-security.xml, in the tag  inside  you must put this:

  authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"