# Spring Security: default-target-url does not work when session expires

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I log in for the first time everything works fine, Spring redirect me to the url specified in default-target-url. 
The problem is when the session expires. If I try to load an URL manually, then Spring redirect me to the login page and after being logged in, Spring redirect me again to the previous URL instead of default-target-url.
I want Spring redirect me to default-target-url always. Here is my configuration:

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/errorPage" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"  access="hasRole('Admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/empresas/**"  access="hasAnyRole('User, Admin')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout#chart" access="hasAnyRole('User, Admin')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/loggedin" 
        authentication-failure-url="/loginError" 
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" 
    />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="true"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
</http>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `always-use-default-target="true"` attribute of form-login. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672850/spring-security-not-hitting-default-target-url-after-successful-authtication) question for more help.

```
<form-login 
    login-page="/login" 
    default-target-url="/loggedin" 
    always-use-default-target="true"        
    authentication-failure-url="/loginError" 
    username-parameter="j_username"
    password-parameter="j_password" 
/>
```

I hope this will help.