# Custom logout URL with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

We follow a certain convention when creating our URIs. All authentication related URIs such as `/login`, `/logout`, `/changepassword` etc fall under the sub-context `/auth`.

Thus our authentication-related URIs look like:

```
/auth/login
/auth/logout
/auth/changepassword
```

This is what we have in the Spring security context XML.

```xml
<http pattern="/auth/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ADMINISTRATIVE_ACCESS"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="XYZ_ACCESS"/>

    <form-login
            login-page="/auth/login"
            default-target-url="/content"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/loginFailed"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <logout logout-url="/auth/logout" logout-success-url="/auth/login"/>
</http>
```

The problem now is that `/auth/logout` gives me a 404 when accessed. However, if I change it to start with something other than `/auth` such as `/abcd/logout` or even `/logout`, it works fine.

I am thinking this is due to the fact that we have defined `/auth/**` as unsecured and yet trying to use it as a logout page. (How can you access logout if you have not logged in?)

Is there any way out of this in order to please our rather strict URI naming convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about the part:

> I am thinking this is due to the fact that we have defined `/auth/**` as
>   unsecured and yet trying to use it as a logout page. (How can you
>   access logout if you have not logged in?)

More precise defining

```
<http pattern="/auth/**" security="none" />
```

means no Spring Security filter is applied to requests that match `/auth/**` pattern and hence Spring Security does not controll `/auth/logout` URL while it should.

Because Spring Security matches pattern from top to bottom simple override for `/auth/logout` in your main `<http>` won't work, so solution to that problem can be defining separate patterns:

```
<http pattern="/auth/login" security="none" />
<http pattern="/auth/changepassword" security="none" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ADMINISTRATIVE_ACCESS"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="XYZ_ACCESS"/>
    <!-- rest of your config -->
</http>
```

If you have many of `/auth/*` URLs to be handled, you can use `<http>`'s [`request-matcher="regex"`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http-request-matcher), but I don't think it'll be readable that way.

Comment: Thanks. It works if I define the rules this way. However, post login, if the user tries to access `/auth/login` the page just loads instead of redirecting to the `default-target-url`. Now that I have declared `security="none"` for `/auth/login`, Spring security ignores it completely.

Comment: You mean that earlier, when authenticated, user who manually hit `/auth/login` was redirected to `default-target-url`?

Comment: It didn't but I believe I could've done something within the `<http>` tag. Now that it is out of security context, it completely rules the possibility out.

Comment: And what if you put `/auth/login` in main `http` like `<intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>`?

Comment: That results in a redirect loop, causing my browser (Firefox) to complain `The page isn't redirecting properly`. In the logs I see a recursive `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied` being thrown.

Comment: Hmm, try `<intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>` and then try again or change  login controller in which you'll have access to authentication object (either anonymous or fully authenticated). Do the redirect to `/content` if it's anonymous, display login form otherwise. Downside is that this solution is not handled by Spring Security config.

Comment: BTW: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657947/spring-is-not-redirecting-to-default-target-url) Spring Security's dev Rob Winch clarifies that _`default-target-url` will only be used if the user logged in without requesting a protected resource first_, so try `always-use-default-target="true"`.

Comment: The problem was `authentication-success-handler-ref`. Spring clearly states "_Should not be used in combination with default-target-url (or always-use-default-
 target-url) as the implementation should always deal with navigation to the subsequent destination_". I removed the default-* attributes and extended `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and the redirect problem for bookmarked links is fine now. However, the `/auth/login` redirect problem still prevails. I will ask another question specific to that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `security="none"`, I think you want `access="permitAll"` ([explanation of permitAll in the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)).

I'm not sure what `security="none"` is supposed to do, but I think you might have it confused with `filters="none"`, which causes [the Spring Security chain to be bypassed completely](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#d0e7366).

Comment: `security="none"` is Spring Security's 3.1 way of bypassing its filters [instead of old `filters="none"`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ftn.d0e832)