# spring-boot using multiple view resolvers from xml configuration not redirecting correctly

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a legacy application using spring xml which I am migrating to spring-boot.

The application starts and I get the authentication page, mapped in the **applicationContext-login.xml**. On login successful it should load WEB-INF/client/home.jsp, but, instead, it tries to load /WEB-INF/auth/home.jsp and I get 404.
In the startup log I see it mapping all the paths. **Why is it conflicting on these redirects and what can I do to fix this?** Does it encounter issues because of multiple @ImportResource containing view resolvers?

Extract from security http configuration:

```
    <s:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <s:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
                      login-processing-url="/auth/j_spring_security_check"
                      authentication-failure-url="/auth/login-secure?loginFailed=true"
                      default-target-url="/auth/defaultEntry"/>
        <s:logout logout-url="/auth/logout" logout-success-url="/auth/logout-success" delete-cookies="jsessionid"/>
    </s:http>
```

The controller it points to:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/defaultEntry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultEntry() {
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
              return "redirect:/client/home";
        } else {
            return "redirect:login";
        }
    }
```

The application has multiple view resolvers configured in xml files:

- **classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-login.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
      default-init-method="init"
      default-destroy-method="destroy">

    <import resource="applicationContext-web-common.xml" />

    <!-- Static login resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/auth/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/auth/assets/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/auth/js/"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.myCompany.auth" />

    <!-- view resolver for JSP -->
    <bean id="loginViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/auth/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"/>
    </bean>
  ```
- **classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-client.xml"**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
        default-init-method="init"
        default-destroy-method="destroy">

      <import resource="applicationContext-web-common.xml" />

      <context:component-scan base-package="org.myCompany.client" />

      <!-- Static resources -->
      <mvc:resources mapping="/player/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/player/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/css/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/data/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/data/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/js/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/locales/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/locales/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/media/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/media/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/index.html" location="/WEB-INF/client/index.html"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/test.html" location="/WEB-INF/client/test.html"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/admin/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/admin/"/>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/documentation/**" location="/WEB-INF/client/documentation/"/>


      <bean id="clientViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/client/"/>
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>


  </beans>
  ```

There are also a few others following the same configuration pattern.

I am loading the resources in the **Application.java**

```
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
    //@EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan({"org.myCompany"})
    @ImportResource({"classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-controllers.xml",
            "classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-rest.xml",
            "classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-login.xml",
            "classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-client.xml",
            "classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-admin.xml",
            "classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-logging.xml",
            "classpath*:/springContext/applicationContext-web-common.xml"
    })
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
            ApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
            Environment env = ctx.getEnvironment();

            logger.info(String.format("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                            "Application '%s' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
                            "Local: \t\thttp://localhost:%s\n\t" +
                            "External: \thttp://%s:%s\n----------------------------------------------------------",
                    env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
                    env.getProperty("server.port"),
                    InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
                    env.getProperty("server.port")));
        }

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean restDispatcher() {
            ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet(),
                    "/rest/*", "/websocket/*");
            registration.setName("rest-dispatcher");
            registration.setLoadOnStartup(2);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("contextConfigLocation", "classpath*:springContext/applicationContext-rest.xml");
            registration.setInitParameters(params);
            return registration;
        }

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean authDispatcher() {
            ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet(), "/auth/*");
            registration.setName("auth-dispatcher");
            registration.setLoadOnStartup(2);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("contextConfigLocation", "classpath*:springContext/applicationContext-login.xml");
            registration.setInitParameters(params);
            return registration;
        }

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean clientDispatcher() {
            ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet(), "/client/*");
            registration.setName("client-dispatcher");
            registration.setLoadOnStartup(2);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("contextConfigLocation", "classpath*:springContext/applicationContext-client.xml");
            registration.setInitParameters(params);
            return registration;
        }

    //... other servlets registration, filters registration

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `redirect:/client/home` from your login screen which will get processed by your loginViewResolver:

```
<bean id="loginViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/auth/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

The clientViewResolver does not get invoked since there is no order specified on the view resolvers. You can set the order using the order property.,

Comment: But how come it all works fine on the spring mvc application?

Comment: If you don't specify an order its going to take the default order on both - which means which comes first is not predictable, hence may or may not work.

Comment: Added order 1 to client and 2 to login. Now I just get Request URL:http://localhost:8000/client/home
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: You are redirecting to redirect:/client/home and the view resolver also has prefix WEB-INF/client, so its going to get resolved as WEB-INF/client/client/home.jsp. Also note that you are going to face issues using 2 resolvers - if one cannot find the jsp its not going to pass on control to the second. You need only 1 since both are the same type with just different prefixes.

Comment: I'm aware having multiple view resolvers is not ideal, but I can't refactor the entire application. I just need a way to run it using spring-boot for dev purposes, while not affecting the production build flow. The redirect still does not work. Any recommendation on how to make it work?

Comment: At this point I would suggest turning on spring debug logs. Also son't think you need to refactor entire app - from the configuration you posted you just really don't need 2 view resolvers

Comment: Unfortunately there are not only 2 view resolvers (I simplified the example), and, as you can see, they have quite similar paths. Therefore, my initial question on how to fix the routing issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

I may assume, that this is caused by Spring Security configuration, and does not depend from View Resolvers. It looks like after success login user is being redirected to page, which he tried to access before, and it may not be `/defaultEntry`. Try edit your Spring Security http configuration as follows:

```
<s:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-aref="delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <s:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
                  login-processing-url="/auth/j_spring_security_check"
                  authentication-failure-url="/auth/login-secure?loginFailed=true"
                  default-target-url="/auth/defaultEntry"
                  always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <s:logout logout-url="/auth/logout" logout-success-url="/auth/logout-success" delete-cookies="jsessionid"/>
</s:http>
```

If it helps - you'll get a clue where to look further.

Also, check it out this [StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659393/5954760).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your dispatcher servlet configuration you defined

```
  <bean id="clientViewResolve" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/client/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
```

With that configuration , its likely to get resolved to /WEB-INF/client/client/*.jsp

Its better to use a single viewresolver rather than  complexing the task of having two view resolvers.